# How to compile a matrix in a for cycle?

Tags: python, math, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix with 3 columns and p rows that contains p rows of x, y and z values, later i transpose this matrix and go on. The problem is I do not know how to create this matrix. Any tips?

```
time=np.arange(0,100,1)
fphi = 2 #kampo phi daznis
ftheta = 3 #kampo i daznis
Amp = np.pi/2
phi = ()
theta = ()
print(time)
points = []
for p in time:
    phi = 2*np.pi*fphi*p
    theta = Amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*ftheta*p)
    x = r * np.cos(phi)
    y = r * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta) - h * 
np.sin(theta)
    z = r * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta) + h * 
np.cos(theta)
    points = np.vstack((points, [x, y, z]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

r=10
h=8
time=np.arange(0,100,1)
fphi = 2 #kampo phi daznis
ftheta = 3 #kampo i daznis
Amp = np.pi/2
phi = ()
theta = ()
print(time)
points = []
for p in time:
    phi = 2*np.pi*fphi*p
    theta = Amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*ftheta*p)
    x = r * np.cos(phi)
    y = r * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta) - h * np.sin(theta)
    z = r * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta) + h * np.cos(theta)
    points.append([x,y,z])

result_matrix = np.matrix(points)
```

U can use np.matrix() with a 2-d nested list as parameter